# Как от фильтровать элементы массива GS NULL и Undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

Получаю JSON-объект, затем его обрабатываю. Некоторые элементы массива бывают NULL и Undefined. Как их "экранировать" или отфильтровать что бы при ссылках них небыло ошибки "Undefined"?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а чем не подходит обычная проверка элемента на null и undefined ?

Comment: @Сергей Пряничкин, если вы имеете ввиду вот так, то почему-то не срабатывает.  if( content.newValue == null || content.newValue == undefined){ var newValueG="null"} else { var newValueG = content.newValue.offer.externalId}

Comment: Нужен пример кода, пример данных, и что должно получится. Похоже, что вы получаете не объект, а строку.

Comment: @oshliaer, код  в данном случаене влияет. данные очень большие. Ниже приведу симуляция данных для  объяснения проблемы:

Comment: ассоциативный массив имеет вид: id.order.Item.offer.   id есть во всех строках, а остальные вложенные элементы могут присутствовать или отсутсвовать, принимая значения null и unidentified. Мне нужно обратиться к нижнему вложенному уровню, т.е. "offer". Вот здесь и нарываюсь на unidentified. Как элегантно можно отфильтровать из массива все "строки" , которые содержат null и unidentified?  PS массиве содержится много другой информации,например id.product.xxxxx.yyyy, id.client.xxx.yyy.zzz

Comment: Просто сформулируйте вопрос по правилам сообщества. Вы должны (просто обязаны) предоставить сообществу все данные, чтобы можно было быстро и беспрепятственно воспроизвести проблему. В данном случае могу порекомендовать только консультации. Я работаю по будням.